# How to concatenate two strings without duplicates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I have two strings as below:

```
var str1 = "5YRS,AC,ALAR";
var str2 = "MON,5YRS,TRAU";
```

I want to merge these two strings into one string and to remove duplicates in this.
I tried the below method:

```
var main_str = str1.concat(str2) //result: "5YRS,AC,ALARMON,5YRS,TRAU"
```

Result which i got is getting merged at on end and if i push any string dynamically it is not showing the desired result. Is there any new ES6 implementation to get a method which checks both null check and return unique string values.

Comment: a string by itself has no concept of "duplicates" - you have to break the string up into words first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could join the two strings with an array and then split the values for getting unique results from a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var str1 = "5YRS,AC,ALAR",
    str2 = "MON,5YRS,TRAU",
    joined = Array.from(new Set([str1, str2].join(',').split(','))).join(',');

console.log(joined);
```

Comment: nice answer, although I'd probably make the default parameter to `join` explicit (for readability)

Comment: As we've seen before, the problem is simple and this is a duplicate. Close-vote it instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus, good morning. i was waiting for you ;-)

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you even answer questions like these? For the easy rep?

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not a duplicate. It's about merging string, not array

Comment: @Faly: The only way to do so is to convert the strings to arrays first... The dupe targets answer this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus the question is clearly stated about string manipulation, dynamic entry and duplicates handling using es6. while i drop in the question i have checked it and put it.

Comment: @tracer: The answers of the dupes are also about _"manipulation, dynamic entry and duplicates handling"_. The only ES6 method used here is also available in the dupe target.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set to avoid duplicates:

```js
var str1 = "5YRS,AC,ALAR";
var str2 = "MON,5YRS,TRAU";
var res = [...new Set([...str1.split(','), ...str2.split(',')])].join(',');
console.log(res);
```

OR:

```js
var str1 = "5YRS,AC,ALAR";
var str2 = "MON,5YRS,TRAU";
var res = [...new Set(str1.split(',').concat(str2.split(',')))].join(',');
console.log(res);
```